# How to use LINQ to return a query result to a dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am working on an MVC project. I need to return an object that groups menu items into groups of four to display in the view using foreach iteration. As this is a model being passed to the view, I need to return a non-generic collection class that can be bound on the .cshtml.

My thought is that I could group the list based on some type of count within LINQ to add four new List items to every Dictionary key. However, I haven't found an expression that would suffice to a Dictionary. I could solve this rather easily by creating another method and iterating again through the collection to assign keys based on a count, but it seems like unneeded iteration and bad practice.

Currently, I am working with the following query.

```
        var itemsDict = rssDataContext.rss_Application_Blog_Category_Relationships
            .Where(x => x.Application_Blog.rss_Application.ID == 1)
            .Where(x => x.Blog_Category_ID == 1)
            .Select(x => new MenuItem
            {
            Name = x.rss_Application_Blog.Blog_Title,
            Uri = x.rss_Application_Blog.Blog_Uri,
            ID = x.rss_Application_Blog.ID
            });
```

But is there a way to group this query into groups of 4 class that be populated into Dictionary<int, List<MenuItem>>?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the key is here. I'm sure ToDictionary (or ToLookup) would make this easy, but it's hard to give an example without understanding what you're trying to do. "Some type of count" is pretty vague.

Comment: Essentially, I need to group the query into groups of 4, so 4 list items are contained in every sublist, but I can't return this to a generic type. Hence, it must be returned to a collection type that will hold many sublists.

Comment: "As this is a model being passed to the view, I need to return a non-generic collection class" why? you can use generic types for views (as long as they are not open E.g. you can use `IGrouping<int,List<MenuItem>>` but not `IGrouping<TKey,TElement>`

Comment: on which property do you wish to group? You say some kind of count, but count of what?

Comment: That's a valid point. I'd still need a query that would populate the IGrouping<int, List<MenuItem>>, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JonSkeet's solution is pretty good. Here's an alternative implementation using [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) to create the sublists and [ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx) to project them into the final result:

```
var itemsDict = rssDataContext.rss_Application_Blog_Category_Relationships
    .Where(x => x.Application_Blog.rss_Application.ID == 1)
    .Where(x => x.Blog_Category_ID == 1)
    .ToArray()
    .Select((x, index) => new
        {
            Index = index,
            Item = new MenuItem
            {
                Name = x.rss_Application_Blog.Blog_Title,
                Uri = x.rss_Application_Blog.Blog_Uri,
                ID = x.rss_Application_Blog.ID
            }
        });
    .GroupBy(i => i.Index / 4)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key);
```

The resulting sequence will look something like this:

```
items = new Dictionary<int, IGrouping<int>>()
{
    0, new[]
    {
        new { Index = 0, Item = new MenuItem { ... } },
        new { Index = 1, Item = new MenuItem { ... } }
    }
    1, new[]
    {
        new { Index = 2, Item = new MenuItem { ... } },
        new { Index = 3, Item = new MenuItem { ... } }
    }
};
```

Comment: I appreciate the help from everyone. This also throws the NotSupportedException as well though.

Comment: Did you add `ToArray()` or `ToList()` after the last `Where(...)` method?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you could do this:

```
var itemsDict = rssDataContext.rss_Application_Blog_Category_Relationships
    .Where(x => x.Application_Blog.rss_Application.ID == 1)
    .Where(x => x.Blog_Category_ID == 1)
    .Select(x => new { 
        x.rss_Application_Blog.BlogTitle,
        x.rss_Application_Blog.BlogUri,
        x.rss_Application_Blog.ID
    })
    .AsEnumerable() // Do the rest of the query in-process
    .Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
    .ToLookup(pair => pair.index % 4,
              pair => new MenuItem {
                 Name = pair.value.Blog_Title,
                 Uri = pair.value.Blog_Uri,
                 ID = pair.value.ID
              });
```

Note that this returns a `Lookup` rather than a `Dictionary`, but that's actually a closer model for what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, the above query throws the NotSupportedException due to unsupported overload of the select operator.

Comment: That's because the type returned by the `rss_Application_Blog_Category_Relationships` property is an `IQueryable` and the underlying LINQ provider *doesn't support the projection*. You'll have to load the source sequence in memory before applying the `Select` method by adding `ToArray()`or `ToList()`. For example: `.Where(x => x.Blog_Category_ID == 1).ToArray().Select(...)`